# Merge data frames by looping and then return

Tags: r, loops, merge

I am trying to merge data frames by looping and then return the merged files to R memory, but cannot get the last part to work.

Here is my merge_data function:

```
list<-c("df1", "df2")
df1 <- diamonds[1:20,] 
df2 <- diamonds[21:40,]
data2<-diamonds[41:60,]

merge_data <- function(data){
  temp<-merge(data, data2, by.x = "cut", by.y="cut", all.x = T)
  temp[is.na(temp)] <-"none"
  print(temp)
}
```

and the problematic part which is supposed to return merged data frames

```
for(i in list){
  temp<-(merge_data(get(i)))
  return(list[i], temp)
}
```

Comment: You need to specify valid column names to merge by. "name1" and "name2" don't exist in your data.  I'm not sure merging is the right thing if your data frames all have the same column names.  Perhaps you want `rbind` instead???

Comment: this is just an example, yes, I need to merge my original datasets

Comment: data, data2; data2 is fixed in this function

Comment: my problem is in the second part, the first works fine, I don't know how to return the merge data

Comment: Are you trying to save the merged dataframes into `list()` at the end, or have each one be a separate object in memory?

Comment: `for` loops don't have or need returns.

Comment: I'm trying to get each separate merged object in memory

Comment: Take out the `return` in your for loop and look up `assign` function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
for(i in list){
  assign(paste0(i, "_merge"), merge_data(get(i)))
}
```

Might need to play around with the factors after you merge so it doesn't generate `NA`s